# Any ways to filling android bitmap data in NDK as quickly as possible

Tags: android, android-ndk

Now, I'm doing something that care about the speed.

As we know, in *Android 2.2* or above, we can use `libjnigraphics` to filling android Java bitmap data at the NDK level, as it is very fast and have low memory consumption.

But for Android version lower then 2.2, we can only use `int` arrays to do it as a bridge. Slower and higher memory consumption ensues (for temp `int` arrays).

So my question is this, Is there any way to do this as quickly as possible in Android versions lower then Android 2.2?

Thanks.